# Regex Match Inverse/Opposite

Tags: regex

is there a way to do inverse/opposite matching with regex? For example:

```
Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg 6,951 × 4,639; 29.18 MB
Klöntalersee in der Gemeinde Glarus, Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg 6,951 × 4,639; 29.18 MB
Picswiss GR-81-17 Mesocco - Pian San Giacomo.jpg 500 × 333; 55 KB
```

By applying regex, I would like to extract just the parts that do not have dimensions or size. I would like my final output to be:

```
Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg
Klöntalersee in der Gemeinde Glarus, Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg
Picswiss GR-81-17 Mesocco - Pian San Giacomo.jpg
```

Is there a way to do this? I have this giant regex that matches the part for dimensions and size (e.g. 123 x 456; 30 MB) but I would like to match the opposite/inverse of it. This is the regex I have so far.

```
(\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*[×|x|X]{1}\s*)((?:\d+|\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*[;|)|,|\.]{1}(?:[^\d]|$)((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}))(?:\.\d+)?\s(?:(?:(?:[kmgtpKMGTP]{1})(?:[bB]{1}))|(?:[bB][yY][tT][eE][sS]{0,1})))
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Siguza, I don't think it does. I want to be able to match it without using any specific programming language. Currently, I'm trying here: https://regex101.com/r/YbL2Uv/1. I want to match everything except the parts that are being matched right now (so I guess the inverse of what I have matched right now). Is there a way to do this? Specifically for this use case would be great!

Comment: Hmm. I feel like it would be a lot easier to use your current regex (maybe prepend a `\s*` to it) and replace all matches with an empty string, then operate on what remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dimensions and size would always appear in the format shown above, and always at the end of the string, you may match on the following regex pattern:

```regex
^.*?(?=\s+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})* × \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*; \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)? \wB)
```

### Demo

However, a stronger approach here might be to remove the dimensions/sizes from your text, leaving behind what you want to see.  This would also be robust with regard to the dimensions/sizes being anywhere in the text.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Also what if I also want to remove the part that has ".jpg"? For example,  "- 19309690789.jpg" or "- Pian San Giacomo.jpg"?

Comment: Just add `\.jpg` to the start of the lookahead, `^.*?(?=\.jpg\s+\d ...`

Comment: Sorry, I have another follow up.
What if the string doesn't contain any dimensions/sizes info? For example, the string "Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg" instead of "Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg 6,951 × 4,639; 29.18 MB".

How can I write the regex to capture "Kanton Glarus - 19309690789.jpg" even if it doesn't have dimensions/sizes info? Right now, when the string doesn't have dimensions/sizes info, it doesn't capture anything.